# Knowing which fields are updated from ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to add an `after_commit` on update to my model in which I send the updated fields values to another part of my application each time my model object got an update from whatever place in my application.

```
class Product
  after_commit :push_to_socket, on: :update

  def push_to_socket
     # Push the updated fields values to socket
     # fields = {name: 'value', ...}
     # push(fields)
  end
end
```

How to get only the updated fields so I can push them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The updated fields:

```
class Product
  after_update :push_to_socket

  def push_to_socket
     # Push the updated fields values to socket
     # previous_changes captures the changes that were made
     # I don't know how your push method works, but this will slice out the changed attributes
     push(slice(*previous_changes.keys))
  end
end
```